# SystemSound.PlaySystemSound() doesn't produce any sound on one iOS device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

Developing in Monotouch. On one device (iOS 5.1.1) SystemSound.PlaySystemSound() doesn't produce sound. Checked volume, mute, etc. Other applications do sound. Other tested devices running the same version of iOS, app, sdk, etc sound just fine.

Here is my code.

On start

```
AudioSession.Initialize(); 
AudioSession.Category = MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback;   
AudioSession.SetActive(true);
```

Here is the code that invokes PlaySystemSound

```
    static SystemSound WhitSound=null;
    public static void PlayWhit()
    {               
        int _mute=NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.IntForKey("mute");
        if(WhitSound==null)
        {
            WhitSound=SystemSound.FromFile(new NSUrl("Images/whit.aiff"));
            Console.WriteLine("WhitSound = "+WhitSound+"  _mute="+_mute);
        }
        if(WhitSound!=null && _mute == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PLAYING WhitSound....");
            WhitSound.PlaySystemSound();
        }
    }
```

This _mute variable is 0 and Console shows "PLAYING WhitSound...." message while no sound produced. I don't think it is GC that collects WhitSound since it is a static class variable. What I am missing here?

Any thoughts?

Comment: if it only affects one device, then it's something wrong with the device, not your code.  Try rebooting, restoring to factory settings, etc...

Comment: If you try switching to `AVAudioPlayer`, does it work any differently?  Don't worry, it should be a small change to switch.  Using either class is fine for this.

Comment: Use AVAudioPlayer fixed the problem though one audio file still doesn't sound on that one iPad

Comment: It was an obscure Mute button in Multitask bar at the bottom. Still don't understand why some files produce sound while other are not when Mute button is on.